# Swift override property set hidden like ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiview

In ObjectiveC i use setHidden to invalidate intrinsic size

```
- (void)setHidden:(BOOL)hidden {
    super.hidden = hidden;
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}
```

and then i call it on some view like

```
view.hidden = YES;
```

but i can't find how to do same on swift

Answer (score 20, accepted):

in swift it's easy, if this is what you meant

```
class myCustomView: UIView {

    override var isHidden: Bool {
        get {
            super.isHidden
        }
        set {
            super.isHidden = newValue
            someOtherFunction()
        }
    }
}

var view = myCustomView()
view.isHidden = true
```

Comment: change `hidden` to `isHidden`